# LockerService and WebSocket

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

In a lightning community with LockerService enabled, I am trying to instantiate a websocket using `new WebSocker('wss://xyz.com')`, but I am unable to because of the way `WebSocket` is implemented in `SecureWindowHelper`. It uses the `SecureObject.$createFilteredMethod$` which returns a function instead of an "newable" object.

Here's the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
>           at WrappedWebSocket (:30:55)
>           at new value (https://livepreview.na40.force.com/clean/s/sfsites/auraFW/javascript/yFpIOtval-qIdUy0rMdm1A/aura_proddebug.js:17508:45)
>           at eval (eval at evaluate (:85:21), :1:12)
>           at WrappedWebSocket (:30:55)
>           at new value (https://livepreview.na40.force.com/clean/s/sfsites/auraFW/javascript/yFpIOtval-qIdUy0rMdm1A/aura_proddebug.js:17508:45)

Also, on the [Locker Service API explorer](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/secureWindow.app?aura.mode=DEV), web sockets are supported.

Any workaround?

Comment: Hi MAV, welcome to SFSE! No need to add thanks or your name in your posts. They just add noise and will be removed.

Comment: I've mentioned you on a post in the Partner Community regarding a conversation about this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WebSocket will be exposed in Summer '17 and you can instantiate a WebSocket instance like in your example.